# Error From res_odbc

Tags: centos, odbc, asterisk, pbx, elastix

I have connected my odbc to MSSQL server and I'm getting sip accounts and dialplan from that and I also can call between two peers but asterisk gets error :

```
'[Jan 26 16:43:16] WARNING[32715]: res_odbc.c:661 ast_odbc_prepare_and_execute: SQL Execute error -1! Verifying connection to MSSQL [MSSQL]...
[Jan 26 16:43:16] WARNING[32715]: res_odbc.c:765 ast_odbc_sanity_check: Connection is down attempting to reconnect...
[Jan 26 16:43:16] NOTICE[32715]: res_odbc.c:1528 odbc_obj_connect: Connecting MSSQL
[Jan 26 16:43:16] NOTICE[32715]: res_odbc.c:1567 odbc_obj_connect: res_odbc: Connected to MSSQL [MSSQL]
[Jan 26 16:43:16] WARNING[32715]: res_odbc.c:649 ast_odbc_prepare_and_execute: SQL Execute returned an error -1: 42000: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The invalid escape character "\\" was specified in a LIKE predicate. (89)
[Jan 26 16:43:16] WARNING[32715]: res_odbc.c:661 ast_odbc_prepare_and_execute: SQL Execute error -1! Verifying connection to MSSQL [MSSQL]...
[Jan 26 16:43:16] WARNING[32715]: res_odbc.c:765 ast_odbc_sanity_check: Connection is down attempting to reconnect...
[Jan 26 16:43:16] NOTICE[32715]: res_odbc.c:1528 odbc_obj_connect: Connecting MSSQL
[Jan 26 16:43:16] NOTICE[32715]: res_odbc.c:1567 odbc_obj_connect: res_odbc: Connected to MSSQL [MSSQL]
[Jan 26 16:43:16] WARNING[32715]: res_odbc.c:649 ast_odbc_prepare_and_execute: SQL Execute returned an error -1: 42000: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The invalid escape character "\\" was specified in a LIKE predicate. (89)
[Jan 26 16:43:16] WARNING[32715]: res_odbc.c:661 ast_odbc_prepare_and_execute: SQL Execute error -1! Verifying connection to MSSQL [MSSQL]...
[Jan 26 16:43:16] WARNING[32715]: res_odbc.c:765 ast_odbc_sanity_check: Connection is down attempting to reconnect...
[Jan 26 16:43:16] NOTICE[32715]: res_odbc.c:1528 odbc_obj_connect: Connecting MSSQL
[Jan 26 16:43:16] NOTICE[32715]: res_odbc.c:1567 odbc_obj_connect: res_odbc: Connected to MSSQL [MSSQL]
[Jan 26 16:43:16] WARNING[32715]: res_odbc.c:649 ast_odbc_prepare_and_execute: SQL Execute returned an error -1: 42000: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The invalid escape character "\\" was specified in a LIKE predicate. (89)
[Jan 26 16:43:16] WARNING[32715]: res_odbc.c:661 ast_odbc_prepare_and_execute: SQL Execute error -1! Verifying connection to MSSQL [MSSQL]...
[Jan 26 16:43:16] WARNING[32715]: res_odbc.c:765 ast_odbc_sanity_check: Connection is down attempting to reconnect...
[Jan 26 16:43:16] NOTICE[32715]: res_odbc.c:1528 odbc_obj_connect: Connecting MSSQL
[Jan 26 16:43:16] NOTICE[32715]: res_odbc.c:1567 odbc_obj_connect: res_odbc: Connected to MSSQL [MSSQL]'
```

Comment: I got same warning message on asterisk 13.3.2 (official package from http://packages.asterisk.org/centos/6/asterisk-13/x86_64/RPMS/). OS: CentOS 6.7

Answer (score 0):

As clearly state in asterisk [documentation](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Configuring+res_odbc) you have option for escape charaster which is probably incorrect set in your config.

in sample config file:

```
; Is the backslash a native escape character?  The default is yes, but for
; MS SQL Server, the answer is no.
;backslash_is_escape => yes
```

Comment: If you changed that param and still not work, i think you should debug source code to see if this param work in your asterisk version or not.

Comment: Teach yourself c/c++ in 21 day and read asterisk source code.

Comment: What you expected on question "how to debug source code"? Sure you need know basic of programing for that